# Problems installing MariaDB

Tags: centos, mariadb

I have a dataset with 166791718 lines in it and I want to use SQL to manage the data. In order to use the language, I need to install it in my machine.

However, I'm having problems installing MariaDB in a Cent OS 7 machine. I run

```
$ sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

and this is the output I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.globo.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-server.x86_64 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBI for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb.x86_64 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.023-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.627-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlServer) >= 0.2001 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlClient) >= 0.2000 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-PlRPC.noarch 0:0.2020-14.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon) >= 0.13 for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Log) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Test) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Zlib) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.061-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-Daemon.noarch 0:0.48-5.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.061-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.061-4.el7 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-5.6.23-3.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 for package: 1:mariadb-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 for package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 (centos-7)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (centos-7)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.i686 (centos-7)
              ~mariadb-libs(x86-32) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.47-1.el7_2.x86_64 (centos-7)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.x86_64 (centos-7)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.44-2.el7.centos
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.i686 (centos-7)
              ~mariadb-libs(x86-32) = 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I already tried to run

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server --skip-broken
```

and

```
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same kind of issues, close to those topics as well:

> _http://serverfault.com/questions/738242/reinstalling-mysql-on-centos-giving-conflicts
>   _http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82076/error-while-installing-perl-dbd-mysql

My system is a CentOS 7 64bits in a virtual machine.
Here are the steps I followed which solved the problem:

1) set up the MariaDB.repo

> source: _https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mariadb-10-on-centos-6/

```
$ nano /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

(save: ctrl+y, then y, then Carriage-Return)

2) use the correct GPG key for mysql

```
update content of /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql with _http://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
$ vi /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-MySql.repo 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

3) activate mariadb.service

> source: _https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-mariadb-on-centos-7

```
$ systemctl start mariadb.service
$ systemctl enable mariadb.service
$ systemctl is-active mariadb.service
```

4) exclude mariadb from yum

> source: _https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/mariadb-error-while-yum-update-with-centos-7/4439

```
$ vi /etc/yum.conf file
exclude=mariadb*
```

5) deactivate mariadb.service due to conflicts between mariadb and mysql

> source: _https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=52860

```
$ systemctl stop mariadb.service
$ systemctl disable mariadb.service
```

6) Upgrade your system

```
$ yum upgrade
```

I hope you'll find some hints within those steps. Sorry for the "_http", but as it's my first post here, I can't add more than 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the CentOS plugin **protectbase** this plugin will help when dealing with multiple 3rd party repos or just `EPEL/RPMForge`

You can use "`yum --disablerepo=[reponame]`" but that's a single use option if you'd like to protect your system continuously then I'd highly recommend the "protectbase"

```
"yum install yum-plugins-protectbase"
```

Then add "`protect=1`" on the repos you'd want to protect. Aka CentOS-Base
And add "protect=0" to epel.repo this should solve most common conflicts when dealing with 3rd party repositories.

I created a more in-depth guide on my blog here [Dealing with multiple repositories on CentOS 4/5/6/7](https://zm.nubes.ca/dealing-with-multiple-repositories-on-centos-4-5-7-with-yum-and-protectbase-plugin-1053/)